# Daily New Users on Fabric consistently far higher than device installs on Play Console

Tags: android, google-fabric, google-play-console

For my android app, I've noticed that the "Daily New Users" metric on Fabric is consistently far higher than the "Total Installs by Device" metric on the Google Play Console.

Each day for the last month, I see ~100 Total Installs By Device on Play Console, and ~200-400 Daily New Users on Fabric. As far as I'm aware, these two metrics should roughly measure the same thing. If anything, I'd expect Fabric to be lower, as I believe Fabric only counts installs if the app gets opened, whereas Google Play Console measures installs even if the app never gets opened.

Can anyone help me understand why I'm seeing such a large discrepancy?

Comment: I also experience significant differences. Todd Burners answer below is good, but in no way explains the differences I see. There must be much more to it. Frustrating that nobody has an explanation

Answer (score 2):

That's very interesting. There are a couple possibilities here:

1 - If you are using a very old version of our SDK it is possible that some new sessions are being registered as new users. We've seen this before but it's pretty infrequent.

2 - You are using automated testing. Fabric doesn't actually use a specific device identifier but will generate it on first run. This means that each install-device pair counts as a new user.

3 - Google accounts associated with new play users, this means cross device users only count as 1. In Fabric, a user is an app-installation pair which means it will likely be higher.

4 - Google Play only counts Google Play installs, Fabric counts installs from all sources.

Thanks!